# What "pixel velocity" should I give to my animation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was thinking if should I ask this question on StackOverFlow or MathStackExchange, decided that it fits here more. I have an icon on my window, moving from point $A(x,y)$ to point $B(x_1,y_1)$. **The starting point of the plane is the top left corner.** Suppose that, $A(100,100)$ ; $B(200,200)$ and I want my character to go from $A$ to $B$ by the shortest possible path - a straight line between these 2 points. In the example I gave, I will just go 1 pixel right and 1 pixel down every 10ms - so my *pixel velocity* for both $x$ and $y$ is 1.

But what if the straight line between 2 points is not a diagonal (e.g $A(100,100)$ $B(120,270)$)? I don't understand how to calculate the *pixel velocity* for these 2 points.

Comment: What do you mean by  "Suppose that $A(100,100)$"?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of point $A$ on the plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, the character needs to move at different velocities in $x$ and $y$. It has to move $20$ pixels to the right and $170$ pixels down. So the $y$ pixel velocity needs to be $\frac{170}{20}$ faster than the $x$ pixel velocity. The pixel needs to travel $8$ times down and one both down and right. Therefore, the $y$ pixel velocity is still $1$, but the $x$ pixel velocity is just $\frac{1}{9}$. The ratio of speeds is  a bit larger than $\frac{170}{20}$ so you need to make some adjustment for the last step.